# Hover effect on current element is not working

Tags: html, css, rating

I am implementing a simple CSS rating widget. So far everything is working fine but I'm facing this simple issue.
On hovering over the current star, it does not change the colour of the star, but if I click on the current star it works as expected.

I guess this is where the problem is.

```css
.rating label.rate:hover ~ label.rate:before {
     color: #FD4;
}
```

```css
div.rating {
    display: inline-block;
}

.rating input.rate { 
    display: none; 
}

.rating label.rate {
    float: right;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: #444;
}

.rating label.rate:hover ~ label.rate:before {
    color: #FD4;
}

.rating input.rate:checked ~ label.rate:before {
    color: #FD4;
}
    
label.rate:before {
    content: '*';
}
```

```html
<div class="rating">        
    <input class="rate" id="star-5" type="radio" name="rate" value="5"/>
    <label class="rate" for="star-5"></label>
    <input class="rate" id="star-4" type="radio" name="rate" value="4"/>
    <label class="rate" for="star-4"></label>
    <input class="rate" id="star-3" type="radio" name="rate" value="3"/>
    <label class="rate" for="star-3"></label>
    <input class="rate" id="star-2" type="radio" name="rate" value="2"/>
    <label class="rate" for="star-2"></label>
    <input class="rate" id="star-1" type="radio" name="rate" value="1"/>
    <label class="rate" for="star-1"></label>          
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your CSS applies to the previous elements but not to the current.

```css
.rating label.rate:hover ~ label.rate:before,
.rating label.rate:hover:before {
    color: #FD4;
}
```

Complete code:

```css
div.rating {
  display: inline-block;
}

.rating input.rate {
  display: none;
}

.rating label.rate {
  float: right;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #444;
}

.rating label.rate:hover~label.rate:before,
.rating label.rate:hover:before {
  color: #FD4;
}

.rating input.rate:checked~label.rate:before {
  color: #FD4;
}

label.rate:before {
  content: '*';
}
```

```html
<div class="rating">
  <input class="rate" id="star-5" type="radio" name="rate" value="5" />
  <label class="rate" for="star-5"></label>
  <input class="rate" id="star-4" type="radio" name="rate" value="4" />
  <label class="rate" for="star-4"></label>
  <input class="rate" id="star-3" type="radio" name="rate" value="3" />
  <label class="rate" for="star-3"></label>
  <input class="rate" id="star-2" type="radio" name="rate" value="2" />
  <label class="rate" for="star-2"></label>
  <input class="rate" id="star-1" type="radio" name="rate" value="1" />
  <label class="rate" for="star-1"></label>
</div>
```